# Unset is not working in this specific example

Tags: php

I have a project that I need to finish before July, it's for school.
It was all going well until I started having problems with an array that comes from my database.
Please keep in mind that this is my first time with PHP and I'm learning as I am doing:

My database has a table named "Pessoas" and another named "Pessoas_Pessoas". The second was to keep the record of relationships between entries on the "Pessoas" table ( for example, if the ID 1 had a relationship with the ID 2, the information would be kept on "Pessoas_Pessoas" ).
The tricky part is that I am supposed to use PHP to prevent the user from duplicating a relationship. 
A good example would be Facebook's friend system:
If I would be friend's with John, it wouldn't appear his profile on the "People you might know" section.

Since I am using MVC and Slim Framework, I managed to get what I want from the database on the model, but I have this problem on the Controller:

[This is an image from the table "Pessoas_Pessoas", being id_PessoasA the id of the profile being visualized and id_PessoasB the id of the profile I'm trying to make a relationship with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hri5b.png)


I managed to get 5 profiles to test this feature and I managed to get those relationships as well, but the problem is that when I try to verify if the id of each profile is the same has id_PessoasB to then unset from the array, but it only works one time even if the condition is true. Here's the code:

```
foreach ($resultadoRelacao as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($resultadoRelacao0 as $key0 => $value0) {
        if ($value0['id'] == $value['id_PessoasB']) {
            $indice = array_search($value0['id'], $resultadoRelacao0);
            unset($resultadoRelacao0[$indice]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time and please ask anything if needed. I'm not really sure what's needed anymore, I'm stuck for 2 weeks.

Comment: paste your array

Comment: Show how you populate the arrays. And keep in mind that `array_search` will return the _first_ key it there are more than one matches and `false` if there are none.

Comment: Can you explain where `$resultadoRelacao` and `$resultadoRelacao0` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the `foreach()` to go through the array and you have matched the element against the one your looking for, you can then use the key value (in this case `$key0`) of the `foreach()` to remove the element your currently looking at...

```
foreach ($resultadoRelacao as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($resultadoRelacao0 as $key0 => $value0) {
        if ($value0['id'] == $value['id_PessoasB']) {
            unset($resultadoRelacao0[$key0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! Gosh, that really slipped right through me! Thanks you so so much! You saved me from failing my last year of school!

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($resultadoRelacao as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($resultadoRelacao0 as $key0 => $value0) {
        if ($value0['id'] == $value['id_PessoasB']) {
            if(($indice = array_search($value0['id'], $resultadoRelacao0)) !==false){

            unset($resultadoRelacao0[$indice]);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, explain your solution.